# Yii2 advanced structure(need another application like frontend/backend)

Tags: php, yii2

I've started recently working with yii2.Using the basic app is easy but what I need to do now is to create an advanced template which has more that frontend and backend.I need it to also have midend and one more compoenent(same as frontend/backend folders).I have been trying to search on the internet but I did not find anything usefull.

I would be grateful if any of you guys can help me out here.

Best regards,
Marius

Comment: Please use the official documentation: «Adding more applications»
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-adding-more-apps.md

Answer (score 4):

Copy the backend folder to a new folder, search for "backend" in the project and replace / add a link to the new folder you have created.

There are not so many places, there is one in common/config/bootstrap.php and the rest I believe are in the new "backend" folder. Remember to change the namespaces of controllers / models etc.

I have made this recently, it is easier then you think.

Comment: Thank you.I was thinking to do this.I wished there was another way to generate all these.

Comment: It is quite easy, you will have it up and running in no time.

Comment: @MihaiP. i want to add 3rd folder in advanced template.. how can i do that?

Comment: quite easy, just copy paste backend, rename it to something else and search for backend in the code. See where you need to change it.